# Spring boot security does not work on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-boot, spring-security

After unsuccessfully searching for a solution I finally gave up. I am trying to deploy a test application which uses Spring Boot and Spring Security. When I run my application locally everything works perfectly fine - there are no errors or exceptions, and the application handles spring security well.

I use `Gradle` to build the project and then deploy it to Google App Engine. Before deploying I am trying to run my project locally by using the Google App Engine `Gradle` plugin, more specifically by using the `appengineRun` Gradle task.

After executing this particular task my application starts up normally, but when I try to access "/" on my localhost, the 403 error appears. I have no web.xml configuration file in my project, although I don't think that this is the crux of the matter. I do have an appengine-web.xml file, which is required by Google App Engine.

What would I to do to get my app working with this particular App Engine task? My main goals are to deploy the Spring Boot application on GAE and get Spring Security to work.

I include my java classes, build.gradle file and WEB-INF contents:

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:+'
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.0.RELEASE")

    }
}
repositories {

    maven {
        url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'war'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    bootJar {
        baseName = 'gs-spring-boot'
        version = '0.1.0'
    }

    dependencies {
        compile group: 'com.google.appengine', name: 'appengine-api-1.0-sdk', version: '1.9.63'
        providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
        compile 'jstl:jstl:1.2'
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
        compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator', version: '2.0.0.RELEASE'
        compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security', version: '2.0.0.RELEASE'
        compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud:+'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        testCompile 'com.google.truth:truth:0.33'
        testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19'
        testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-testing:+'
        testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-stubs:+'
        testCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-tools-sdk:+'
    }

    appengineDeploy.dependsOn test
    appengineStage.dependsOn test

    appengine {
        run {
            port = 8090
        }

        deploy {   // deploy configuration
        }
    }

    test {

        useJUnit()
        testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
        beforeTest { descriptor ->
            logger.lifecycle("test: " + descriptor + "  Running")
        }

        onOutput { descriptor, event ->
            logger.lifecycle("test: " + descriptor + ": " + event.message)
        }
        afterTest { descriptor, result ->
            logger.lifecycle("test: " + descriptor + ": " + result)
        }
    }

    group = "com.example.appenginej8"
    version = "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
}
```

appengine-web.xml:

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <version>1</version>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <runtime>java8</runtime>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Application.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("packages")
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

MyController.java:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {


    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String hello() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

SecurityConfig.java:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

        @Bean
        public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
            InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
            manager.createUser(User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("user").password("password").roles("ADMIN").roles("ACTUATOR").build());
            return manager;
        }
}
```

Comment: Someone help, please :)

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with Spring Boot Security. I completed removed the `SecurityConfig` class, and the local dev sever still returns 403.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need `SpringBootServletInitializer` to magically make Spring Boot function as a traditional Servlet WAR.

```java
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
  }

}
```

This should make it work basically. I noticed you would still hit a different but minor issue after adding this class, but it should be trivial to fix.

Comment: @mrrobot1337, if you consider Chanseok's answer is valid for you, please consider accepting it. Thank you.